# How to lock Parent Window in JavaFx when Jasper Report is visible in popup

Tags: javafx, jasper-reports

For creating Jasper Report in JavaFX 11 I am using dynamic reports. When I click on button Jasper Report open and visible inside a popup. But I can click the button as many number of times as I want and the report will open those number of times. But I want to lock parent window once the jasper report is visible so that the parent window is reachable only after closing the popup. The same thing we can achieve in Parent and Child Window as explained in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625987/block-owner-window-java-fx) but I want to achieve similar thing with Parent as my stage and child being a Jasper Window. Code for the same is mentioned below:-

**JavaFxJasperReportsDemo.java**

```
package demo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.DynamicReports;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.column.Columns;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.component.Components;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.datatype.DataTypes;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.constant.HorizontalTextAlignment;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.exception.DRException;

public class JavaFxJasperReportsDemo extends Application{

    @FXML
    private StackPane stackPane;

    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{

        try{
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/FXMLJavaFXJasperReportsDemo.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.setTitle("Java FX Demo");
            stage.show();
            stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
                public void handle(WindowEvent arg0) {
                    Platform.exit();
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            throw e;
        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void loadReport(ActionEvent event) {
        JasperReportBuilder report = DynamicReports.report();
        List<DemoPOJO> lstDemoPOJOs=new ArrayList<DemoPOJO>();
        DemoPOJO demoPOJO=new DemoPOJO();
        demoPOJO.setName("ABC");
        demoPOJO.setCity("Delhi");
        lstDemoPOJOs.add(demoPOJO);
        demoPOJO = new DemoPOJO();
        demoPOJO.setName("XYZ");
        demoPOJO.setCity("Agra");
        lstDemoPOJOs.add(demoPOJO);
        report
        .columns(
                Columns.columnRowNumberColumn("S No"),
                Columns.column("Name", "name", DataTypes.stringType()),
                Columns.column("Address", "city", DataTypes.stringType())
                ).title(
                        Components.text("Demo Java Fx Jasper Reports").
                        setHorizontalTextAlignment(HorizontalTextAlignment.CENTER))
        .pageFooter(Components.pageXofY())
        .setDataSource(lstDemoPOJOs);
        try {
            report.show(false);
        } catch (DRException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            launch(args);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use an JavaFx Viewer like https://github.com/mgrecol/JasperViewerFx.
Than set the `Modality.WINDOW_MODAL`

Comment: @Raw Can you please show one example and how to use JasperViewerFx in existing JavaFx Project. Is there any maven dependency or any external jar file for the same

Comment: You can download the Sources and add them to your project and just change `JRViewerFx->start()` function.
ADD 
`primaryStage.initOwner(owner);
primaryStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now I don't have a solution based on "reachability" of parent window. But I can provide you an alternate solution to not allow the user to click multiple times. The idea is to disable the scene's root node as soon as you press the button and enabling it only when the report window is closed. Not sure whether this fits your purpose.

```
reportButton.setOnAction(e -> {
    // Get root node of the scene
    Node sceneRoot = ((Node)e.getTarget()).getScene().getRoot();

    // First things first, disable it !!
    sceneRoot.setDisable(true);

    // Your actual method for showing report
    loadReport(e);
    
    // Get all current AWT windows.
    java.awt.Window[] windows = java.awt.Window.getWindows();

    // Get the recently added window (your report window) and add a close listener.
    windows[windows.length-1].addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
            // When the window is closed, enable your root node.
            sceneRoot.setDisable(false);
        }
    });
});
```

*Note: The internal implementation of JasperReportBuilder's JasperViewer is a JFrame.*

**[UPDATE]**

Complete working demo below:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.DynamicReports;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.column.Columns;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.component.Components;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.datatype.DataTypes;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.constant.HorizontalAlignment;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.exception.DRException;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class JavaFxJasperReportsDemo extends Application {

    @FXML
    private StackPane stackPane;

    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        try {
            StackPane root = new StackPane();
            ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
            cm.getItems().addAll(new MenuItem("Test1"), new MenuItem("Test2"));
            Button reportButton = new Button("Report");
            reportButton.setContextMenu(cm);
            reportButton.setOnAction(e -> {
                // Get root node of the scene
                Node sceneRoot = ((Node) e.getTarget()).getScene().getRoot();

                // First things first, disable it !!
                sceneRoot.setDisable(true);

                // Your actual method for showing report
                loadReport(e);

                // Get all current AWT windows.
                java.awt.Window[] windows = java.awt.Window.getWindows();

                // Get the recently added window (your report window) and add a listener.
                windows[windows.length - 1].addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
                    public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
                        // When the window is closed, enable your root node.
                        sceneRoot.setDisable(false);
                    }
                });
            });
            root.getChildren().add(reportButton);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 200);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.setTitle("Java FX Demo");
            stage.show();
            stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
                public void handle(WindowEvent arg0) {
                    Platform.exit();
                }
            });


        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void loadReport(ActionEvent event) {
        JasperReportBuilder report = DynamicReports.report();
        List<DemoPOJO> lstDemoPOJOs = new ArrayList<DemoPOJO>();
        DemoPOJO demoPOJO = new DemoPOJO();
        demoPOJO.setName("ABC");
        demoPOJO.setCity("City 1");
        lstDemoPOJOs.add(demoPOJO);
        demoPOJO = new DemoPOJO();
        demoPOJO.setName("XYZ");
        demoPOJO.setCity("City 2");
        lstDemoPOJOs.add(demoPOJO);
        report
                .columns(
                        Columns.columnRowNumberColumn("S No"),
                        Columns.column("Name", "name", DataTypes.stringType()),
                        Columns.column("Address", "city", DataTypes.stringType())
                ).title(
                Components.text("Demo Java Fx Jasper Reports").
                        setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER))
                //.pageFooter(Components.pageXofY())
                .setDataSource(lstDemoPOJOs);
        try {
            report.show(false);
        } catch (DRException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            launch(args);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if the parent window is having a context menu, even after executing `sceneRoot.setDisable(false);` , the context menu when opened will remain disabled.

Comment: @RenojJoseph, I tried to set the ContextMenu and checked , looks like it is working as expected? Or am I missing something. Updated the answer with the demo I am working. Can you let me know how & where the ContextMenu is set.

Comment: if the source of action is a button every thing is OK. But in my case my window have a button and a table view with context menu. When button is clicked the entire table will be shown in the jasper viewer. After closing the jasper viewer if I open the context menu of the table view it will be active without any problem. My context menu of table view when clicked will open details of the selected row (say an Invoice) in jasper viewer. In this case if I reopen the context menu after closing the jasper viewer the context menu will be disabled.

Comment: I have slightly modified your code in order to get all the open windows to be disabled and the jasper viewer should always be on top and posting the modified code as answer below.

Comment: @RenojJoseph, I am a bit unclear with the workflow you mentioned. My first instinct is it should not have any link to this implementation. Having said that, if you can provide the complete working example of your use case, we can investigate.

Answer (score 0):

This is a modified code of what posted by Sai Dandem. It will disable all the open javafx windows and jasper viewer will always on top. When jasper viewer is closed all the windows will be enabled.

```
public class MakeJasperViewerAsModalWindow {

    public MakeJasperViewerAsModalWindow(JasperViewer jasperViewer) {

        jasperViewer.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

        final java.awt.Window[] windows = java.awt.Window.getWindows();
        final List<Window> windowsfx = Window.getWindows();
        windowsfx.stream().forEach(o -> {

            o.getScene().getRoot().setDisable(true);
        });

        windows[windows.length - 1].addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {

                windowsfx.stream().forEach(o -> {

                    o.getScene().getRoot().setDisable(false);
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

it can be used as `new MakeJasperViewerAsModalWindow(jasperViewer);`